# R ggplot2 : continuous x + colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a boxplot using ggplot2 with :

- X as a continuous variable
- Colors for different groups

Here is an example :

```
    x <- sample(c(1,2,5),300,replace = TRUE)
    y <- sapply(x,function(mu) rnorm(1,mean = mu))
    color <- sample(c("color 1","color 2"),300,replace = TRUE)
    data <- data.frame(x, y, color)
```

I can either have colors and x as a factor :

```
   ggplot(data = data) + geom_boxplot(aes(x = factor(x),y = y,col = color))
```

[image]

or x as a continuous variable and no colors :

```
  ggplot(data = data) + geom_boxplot(aes(x = x,y = y,group = x))
```

[image]
But not both.
Does somebody know how to do this ?
Thanks

Comment: Slightly confused, what's the desired output?

Comment: The desired output is like the first plot but respecting the continuous scale of x. In the first plot, x is considered as a factor.

Comment: x as continous means you want from 1 to 5 in x axis?

Comment: Yes. and the distance between the 1 the 2 and the 5 must not be equal (like plot 2)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need one more column for group, which is the combination of `color` and `x`. For example, how about simply `paste()`ing them?

```r
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(c(1,2,5),300,replace = TRUE)
y <- sapply(x,function(mu) rnorm(1,mean = mu))
color <- sample(c("color 1","color 2"),300,replace = TRUE)
data <- data.frame(x, y, color)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = data) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = x, y = y, col = color, group = paste(color, x)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scales` to change the x-axis scale.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

x <- sample(c(1,2,5),300,replace = TRUE)
y <- sapply(x,function(mu) rnorm(1,mean = mu))
color <- sample(c("color 1","color 2"),300,replace = TRUE)
data <- data.frame(x, y, color)

ggplot(data = data) + geom_boxplot(aes(x = factor(x),y = y,col = color)) + scale_x_discrete(limit = c('1','2','3','4','5'))
```

Hack for dynamic limits:

```
min = min(data$x)

max = max(data$x)

limits <- as.character(seq(min:max))

ggplot(data = data) + geom_boxplot(aes(x = factor(x),y = y,col = color)) + scale_x_discrete(limit = limits)
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the trick, But i'm searching for a more automatic way, without specifying all "limit" values of the scale.

Comment: it work but if i specify x as `x <- sample(c(0.1,0.2,0.5),300,replace = TRUE)` , it no longer works.

Comment: Got it. Kind of have to work out the sequence with `by`

Answer (score 1):

You could misuse the fill aesthetic:

```
ggplot(data = data) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = x, y = y, col = color, fill = factor(x))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rep(NA, 3), guide = "none")
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: i tried to fill the groups and not colorize them it doesn't work : `ggplot(data = data) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = x, y = y, col = factor(x), fill = color)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = rep(NA, 3), guide = "none")`

Comment: Replace `NA` with any color, e.g. with `"black"`.